# Personalized php outputs from different sql tables

Tags: php, sql, while-loop, union

I'm creating a notification page, where
there are 4 types of notification displayed

```
1) someone liked your post
2) someone shared your post
3) someone added you as a friend
4) someone commented your post
```

I've already gotten the sql codes for each statement but I still dont know how to mix everything in a single `while($a=sql_array()){}` loop, I know I should use UNION and ORDER by date, but how do I post a personalized output for each type of notification displayed

```
DESIRED OUTPUT

A liked your page
B comment your post
C liked your page
D comment your post
E added you as a friend
F liked your page
G comment your post
H shared your post
I added you as a friend
J shared your post
K shared your post
L liked your page
M added you as a friend
N shared your post
O added you as a friend
P liked your page
Q comment your post
R added you as a friend
S added you as a friend
T comment your post
D liked your page
```

What I have are 6 tables

```
table_users
table_posts 
table_likes
table_shares
table_comments
table_community
```

Every type of notification follows the same pattern

```
 SELECT u.`name`, p.post, p.date as OrderDate
  FROM likes (next shares, next, comments, community)
    LEFT JOIN Users as u on likes.id_liker=u.id_user
    LEFT JOIN Users as v on likes.liked_user_id=v.id_user
    LEFT JOIN Posts as p on likes.liked_post_id=p.id_post
         WHERE likes.liked_user_id=3
```

So I use `UNION` ordered by `OrderDate`, they retrieve the results but with no personalizad type of notification.I'm trying to summarize because this is huge.

Comment: what do you mean, "no personalized type of notification"?

Comment: for example, first php output lines to be `A added you as a friend`, the second one, `B commented your post`, the third one `C liked your post`, All of them coming from a single `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to format these events differently? This is as easy as adding a discriminator field in the output

```
SELECT "like", u.`name`, p.post, p.date as OrderDate FROM likes ...
UNION
SELECT "share", u.`name`, p.post, p.date as OrderDate FROM shares ...
```

Now in your application you can choose different formatting depending on the value of that first column.

Comment: Lol. So easy. I got it and  have it working. lol.  I used `$type=$row['0'];` and it shows the type of discriminator in the output line.Thank you pretty much!!.